# how to do the multiplication operation on multiple inputs using single button on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

By using this code I can able multiply 2 input values only. But I need to do multiplication the N number of 2 input values by clicking a single button.

- In this stage1 I want to do a multiplication operation by clicking the single button for N no. of input values.
- In Stage2 I want to do multiplication on that result value.
  Like: Width: 20, Height: 10. then
  20 * 10 = 200 * 20(We assign the hard coded value) = 4000.
- In Stage3 I want to print the total output in pdf format.

```js
function divideBy() 
{ 
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        opt = document.getElementById("opt").value;
        var opt = document.getElementById("opt").value;
        if(opt == "Semi Modular")
          mod = ""+num1+"  *  "+num2+"";
        else if (opt == "Full Modular")
            
            mod = "(("+num1+"  *  "+num2+")* "+2+")";
            
        result = eval(mod);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white-space;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=number], input[type=password] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=number]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.registerbtn {
  background-color: #626463;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a blue text color to links */
a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */
.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
p.test{
    margin: 15px 0 5px !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JavaScript program to calculate multiplication and division of two numbers </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="calculation.js"></script>

<form>
<br>
<p Class="test">Master Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
<br>
<p Class="test">Children Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<p Class="test">Guest Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" id="firstNumber" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" id="secondNumber" /> <label for="email"> <span id = "result"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<input type="button" class="registerbtn" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
 
    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you get?

Comment: Actually, It's working well for multiplication operation on 2 inputs. but I want to do that same operation on N no. of 2 inputs by using a single button.  Please review the HTML code once.

Comment: for n number of inputs, you have to get a loop through for each element value and perform multiplication on it.

Answer (score 0):

I done some changes to your code now it's working as expected.
here is the working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
function divideBy() 
{ 
$(".firstNumber").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
debugger
    // Here, array.length is the total number of items
    var num1 = $("#firstNumber"+ index).val();
    var num2 = $("#secondNumber"+ index).val()
    if(num1!="" &&num2!="")
    {
    opt = document.getElementById("opt").value;
        var opt = document.getElementById("opt").value;
        if(opt == "Semi Modular")
          mod = ""+num1+"  *  "+num2+"";
        else if (opt == "Full Modular")
            
            mod = "(("+num1+"  *  "+num2+")* "+2+")";
            
        result = eval(mod);
        document.getElementById("result"+index).innerHTML = result;
    }
     
});

       
       
}
</script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white-space;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=number], input[type=password] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=number]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.registerbtn {
  background-color: #626463;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a blue text color to links */
a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */
.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
p.test{
    margin: 15px 0 5px !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 20%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JavaScript program to calculate multiplication and division of two numbers </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="calculation.js"></script>

<form>
<br>
<p Class="test">Master Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" class="firstNumber" id="firstNumber0" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" class="secondNumber" id="secondNumber0" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result0"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" class="firstNumber" id="firstNumber1" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" class="secondNumber"  id="secondNumber1" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result1"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
<br>
<p Class="test">Children Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" class="firstNumber"  id="firstNumber2" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number"  class="secondNumber"  id="secondNumber2" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result2"></span></label> </br>
<div  class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number" class="firstNumber" id="firstNumber3" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" class="secondNumber" id="secondNumber3" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result3"></span></label> </br>
<div  class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<p Class="test">Guest Bedroom :</p>
 <p>Wardrobe Loft :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number"   class="firstNumber" id="firstNumber4" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" class="secondNumber" id="secondNumber4" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result4"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<! Wardrobes >
<p>Wardrobe :</p>
<label for="email"><b>Width :</b></label> <input type="number"  class="firstNumber" id="firstNumber5" /> 
<label for="email"><b>Height :</b></label> <input type="number" class="secondNumber" id="secondNumber5" /> <label for="email"> <span class="result" id = "result5"></span></label> </br>
<div class="col-lg-1">
                <select id="opt" class="form-control">
                    <option>Semi Modular</option>
                    <option>Full Modular</option>                    
                </select>
            </div>
            
<input type="button" class="registerbtn" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
 
    
</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Neeraj. The code is working well. but when I miss any one of the values. Like, If you miss 2 & 4th-row values and fill them to remain. The code executes only 1-row values only.

Comment: @murthy i update code now check.